# Firebase performance for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-performance

I see that there are plug-ins available for various Firebase services. For example: https://github.com/f-miyu

Is there anything available for Firebase Performance though? I'm searching around, but I don't find anything available.

If nothing is available is there any way to disable and enable monitoring according to the users' settings, in order to comply with consent laws?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase support monitor through Firebase Performance Monitoring.

Key capabilities:

- Automatically measure app startup time, HTTP network requests, and
  more
- Gain insight into situations where app performance could be
  improved
- Customize monitoring for your app

For more details, you could refer to the link below:

- Firebase Performance Monitoring: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon
- How to use add this monitor: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android

Comment: So, I guess there is no way to handle Firebase Performance through my Xamarin.Forms code, right?

Comment: I don't think there is a plug-in at all. I haven't found any.

Comment: Sorry. I miss something.  On specific platform, you could use `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.PerformanceMonitoring ` for ios and Xamarin.Firebase.Perf for Android. But no official for Forms project.

Comment: You could try to use the Dependency service to use the specific platform packages on Xamarin.Forms. But I have's tried yet.